# scroll to a div and add active class to the tab of the current div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrollto

I have 7 tabs

```
<div class="header">
    <input id="example1" type="submit" name="script"  value="Tab 1">
    <input id="example2" type="submit" name="script"  value="Tab 2">
    <input id="example3" type="submit" name="script"  value="Tab 3>
    <input id="example4" type="submit" name="script" value="Tab 4">
    <input id="example5" type="submit" name="script"  value="Tab 5">
    <input id="example6" type="submit" name="script"  value="Tab 6">
    <input id="example7" type="submit" name="script"  value="Tab 7">
</div>
<div id="outputs">
    <div id="output1" style="height:auto; text-align:left;">Some long text</div>
    <div id="output2" style="height:auto; text-align:left;">Some long text</div>
    <div id="output3" style="height:auto; text-align:left;">Some long text</div>
    <div id="output4" style="height:auto; text-align:left;">Some long text</div>
    <div id="output5" style="height:auto; text-align:left;">Some long text</div>
    <div id="output6" style="height:auto; text-align:left;">Some long text</div>
    <div id="output7" style="height:auto; text-align:left;">Some long text</div>
</div>
```

**jquery code is**

```
$("#example1").click(function() {
    $(".single-scroll").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var val = $("#output1").position().top - 135;

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 800);
});
$("#example2").click(function() {
    $(".single-scroll").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var val = $("#output2").position().top - 89;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 800);
});
$("#example3").click(function() {
    $(".single-scroll").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var val = $("div#output3").position().top - 89;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 800);
});
$("#example4").click(function() {
    $(".single-scroll").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var val = $("div#output4").position().top - 89;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 800);
});
$("#example5").click(function() {
    $(".single-scroll").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var val = $("#output5").position().top - 89;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 800);
});
$("#example6").click(function() {
    $(".single-scroll").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var val = $("#output6").position().top - 89;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 800);
});
$("#example7").click(function() {
    $(".single-scroll").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var val = $("#output7").position().top - 89;
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, 800);
});
```

**CSS CODE IS**

```
    .active{
      color:blue;
    }
```

I have tried the above code, it is not working properly. And active class is not added on scroll.

The `header` div is fixed. and when `example1` is clicked the window must scroll to `output1`, when `example2` is clicked the window must scroll to `output2`,

similarly to all the 5 buttons the window must move to corresponding div based on the serial number and on click `active` class must be added to the clicked tab.

similarly when a window is scrolled(not click), if div=output4" is present then the `active` class must be added to `example4`.

I am looking for the functionality same as [this](http://housing.com/in/new-projects/page/264-srisairam-towers-by-srisairam-group-in-hafeezpet?f=eyJjaXR5X2lkIjozNn0%3D)

Comment: its wroking fine class adding http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/9/

Comment: its working for click function, but I don't understand how to get the same functionality when scrolled using mouse. When I scroll using mouse active class must be added to the button corresponding to the div . Check the link U will understand

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/12/

Comment: yea you can manage code for you and you are binding 'example1','example1' .. etc why not simple use class and set data attribute to get destination

Answer (score 1):

With respect to [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/13/) provided by Mohit, exact div alignment in center and highlight the above tab.

you need to edit jsfiddle code with below

```
if ($(this).offset().top > cutoff+200)
```